# iOS7 UIImage drawAtPoint not retina

Tags: ios, image, performance, drawing

i am trying to draw an image with the following code:

```
[img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
```

but the problem is that on an iphone with a retina display the image doesn´t get drawn in retina scale. It seems like the image gets upscaled and then drawn.
I don´t want to use drawInRect because the image is in right size and it´s way slower to use drawInRect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are not setting the appropriate scale factor. When you create the bitmap context one of the arguments is the scale:

```
void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
   CGSize size,
   BOOL opaque,
   CGFloat scale
);
```

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) scale is:

> The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of
>   0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

You're probably passing `1.0f` which will result in the issue you've described. Try passing `0.0f`.